# Add Cordova plugin to Mobile Google Chrome App?

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-app, cordova-chrome-app

I'm using the [Mobile Chrome App Cordova CLI-tool cca](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps) for building my webapp on Android.

Then, I have added a Cordova plugin that I want to be rendered into the Cordova `config.xml` as this:

```
<feature name="Keyboard">
    <param name="ios-package" value="IonicKeyboard" onload="true" />
</feature>
```

How do I specify this addition in my manifest file?

It seems to be detected by cca

```
$ cca plugin ls
cca v0.1.1
com.ionic.keyboard 1.0.2 "Keyboard"
[..]
```

Thankful for any pointers. If it's currently unsupported I could probably help out with building it in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to modify the config.xml or the manifest to do this.  `cca` supports the full command line syntax that `cordova` does, so you should do the same as you usually would:

`cca plugin add com.ionic.keyboard`

And then just use it!

Comment: Thanks! 
`cca plugin add https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard.git` did the trick!

Comment: One caveat to note, we currently remove non-cca plugins when running `cca upgrade` (Sorry! Can follow [issue #272](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/issues/272))